# Mupdf for large PDF

Tags: android, mupdf

I am using Mupdf library voor my android project. everything works fine until if we want to open a langer PDF file > 15MB like this example: http://definecontent.nl/igdas/pdf/11376133.pdf

in the logcat you can see these text:

```
05-21 23:58:54.062: E/libmupdf(25186): Opening document...
05-21 23:58:54.092: I/alert(25186): alert_init
05-21 23:58:54.092: E/libmupdf(25186): Done!
05-21 23:58:54.132: I/alert(25186): Enter startAlerts
05-21 23:58:54.132: I/alert(25186): Exit startAlerts
05-21 23:58:54.132: I/alert(25186): Enter waitForAlert
05-21 23:58:54.202: I/libmupdf(25186): Drop page 0
05-21 23:58:54.202: E/libmupdf(25186): Goto page 0...
05-21 23:58:54.202: I/libmupdf(25186): Load page 0
05-21 23:58:54.212: E/libmupdf(25186): PageWidth=28798
05-21 23:58:54.212: E/libmupdf(25186): PageHeight=2037
05-21 23:58:54.212: E/libmupdf(25186): PageWidth=28798
05-21 23:58:54.212: E/libmupdf(25186): PageHeight=2037
05-21 23:58:54.212: I/libmupdf(25186): In native method
05-21 23:58:54.212: I/libmupdf(25186): Checking format
05-21 23:58:54.212: I/libmupdf(25186): locking pixels
05-21 23:58:54.212: E/libmupdf(25186): Rendering page(0)=768x54 patch=[0,0,768,54]
05-21 23:58:54.212: E/libmupdf(25186): error: image is too wide
05-21 23:58:54.212: E/libmupdf(25186): error: cannot draw xobject/image
05-21 23:58:54.212: E/libmupdf(25186): warning: Ignoring errors during rendering
05-21 23:58:54.212: E/libmupdf(25186): Rendered
```

How can I make sure my android app able to open such large PDF files?  Does Mupdf really support to do that? or do you know which opensource library can help us? shortly, give me advice to fix that! thanks.

Comment: Hey does @Librelio solution worked for you?

Answer (score 3):

MuPDF does support large files. We use it for our magazine apps on Android and it works really well. The source code of our apps is available on [Github](https://github.com/libreliodev/android).

The problem with your specific pdf file is that it contains a very large image, that even Acrobat Pro on a MacBook Air does not manage to display. Your solution would be either to split this image across several pages, or to reduce its pixel size.

Comment: yes you are right, but the problem is that you cannot split some pdf in to pages! because it contains architect map.

Comment: Hi, thanks again for your response, I noticed that mupdf uses that lines code to avoid large images:  f (w > (1 << 16))fz_throw(ctx, "image is too wide"); I am not a c programmer, so I couldn't understand why is 16 there for? do you have any idea? the full version  see here: https://github.com/mariusmuja/mupdf/blob/master/pdf/pdf_image.c

Comment: then how can display the split pdf files... can you please suggest

Comment: how to show loader during loading of large pdf file ? Because it takes more time to load.